# Icons still showing even if it's parent widget's height is zero in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, animatedcontainer

I have an AnimatedContainer and as it's child, I have a Row containing a Text and an IconButton. After clicking some button, I am toggling the height of the Container between 0 and 100. When the Container height is zero, the IconButton is still visible (not the Text) and not clickable. [image]

[image]

```
 Widget _myAnimatedContainer() {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      height: height,
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Animated Container',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: () {},)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

class _AnimatedContainerExampleState extends State<AnimatedContainerExample> {
  double height = 100;
  bool isExpanded = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            _myAnimatedContainer(),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Expand'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                  height = isExpanded ? 100 : 0;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
```

Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the if condition:

```dart
if (height > 0)
     IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: () {},)
```

You might want to use a different value from 0 (like 10) to remove the icon

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem, but i wonder why the IconButton is still visible when the container height is zero, because the Text is working fine as expected.

Comment: You're welcome Ahmad! They are different type of widgets so their implementation in the flutter library also differs. You can raise an issue on their github https://github.com/flutter/flutter if you think that this is an important missing feature, probably many other developers encountered the same problem already.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common issue with the icons and to solve this you could just add `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to the parent Container.